# Dart Streams: How to load balacing?

Tags: dart

Is it possible to make a stream in Dart to load balance its emited datas?
Example:
I have one Stream and 3 listeners (A), (B) and (C):

- Emits 0, (A) receives but not (B) and (C)
- Then it emits 1, (B) receives but not (A) and (C)
- Then it emits 2, (C) receives but not (A) and (B)

How to acomplish it in Dart ?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a draft solution but you can do something like this (and properly add some utility methods like e.g. removing streams when they are stopping listening):

```
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  final splitter = StreamSplitter(
      Stream<int>.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (i) => i));

  splitter
      .getLoadBalancedStream()
      .forEach((element) => print('Called Stream 1 with: $element'));
  splitter
      .getLoadBalancedStream()
      .forEach((element) => print('Called Stream 2 with: $element'));
  splitter
      .getLoadBalancedStream()
      .forEach((element) => print('Called Stream 3 with: $element'));

  // Called Stream 1 with: 0
  // Called Stream 2 with: 1
  // Called Stream 3 with: 2
  // Called Stream 1 with: 3
  // Called Stream 2 with: 4
  // Called Stream 3 with: 5
  // Called Stream 1 with: 6
}

class StreamSplitter<T> {
  List<StreamController<T>> streamControllers = [];

  StreamSplitter(Stream<T> stream) {
    final controller = _controllers().iterator;

    stream.listen((event) => controller
      ..moveNext()
      ..current.add(event));
  }

  Stream<T> getLoadBalancedStream() {
    final controller = StreamController<T>();
    streamControllers.add(controller);

    return controller.stream;
  }

  Iterable<StreamController<T>> _controllers() sync* {
    // ignore: literal_only_boolean_expressions
    while (true) {
      for (var i = 0; i < streamControllers.length; i++) {
        yield streamControllers[i];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You soluttion is great but I was looking for a way of doing it with extensions and without the need to encapsulate a stream inside a class. I foudn a solution for that, will post it here.

Comment: Very nice. For a complete solution, it should probably also remove cancelled or paused balancer-streams. Maybe something like: https://gist.github.com/lrhn/495e5e4b0ae6e6a40642eac88dd59af7

Comment: @lrn Great solution which I think is a good candidate to be added to a package like `async` (not `dart:async`). I don't know why I completely forgot `Queue` which makes totally sense to use. :)

Comment: If you want efficient `remove` operations, you can use a linked hash set instead of a `Queue`. It makes `var x= set.first; set.remove(first); set.add(first)` behave like a queue. Probably less efficient than the `Queue`, but then the out-of-order remove is not linear.